# JS FormData object not defined for PhoneGap in Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I made an iPhone app with PhoneGap and used a Javascript FormData object to POST data to a server using AJAX. I then tried to do the same for an Android app but get the JS error:

```
ReferenceError: FormData is not defined
```

Any idea why I get the JS error with one platform using PhoneGap but not the other? (And if it is fixable). Code I'm using it for is to upload an image:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append( 'file', $('.user-photo')[0].files[0] );
fd.append('lat', lat);
fd.append('lon', lon);
fd.append('uuid', uuid);

$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'http://myurl.com/do-something',
     data: fd,
     processData:false,
     contentType:false,
     success:function(res) {
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out FormData objects don't work with Android on PhoneGap.

Comment: Hi, would you please explain a bit more? How it doesn't work. In my case, it finds the FormData object correctly and am able to submit request via Jquery Ajax. After that when the success call back comes back then it returns nothing. Is this the same thing you faced?

Comment: is there an answer to that question?