# Uncaught ReferenceError: FormData is not Defined in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I currently build mobile application, I'm using PhoneGap (Cordova) as my framework to build my application.

I want to ask, why there's Uncaught ReferenceError on my eclipse console when I try to submit the form (I test it on my android phone, with android version 2.3.6)?
I'm trying compile it on GoogleChrome browser (Also Firefox) on there, I'm not getting error.

Here's my code :

Ajax (I'm using Ajax and also JQuery) :

```
function updateUser() { 

        /*get data from ID in updateprofile.html*/
        var IDUser = sessionStorage.Uid_user;
        var fname = $("#INAwal").val();
        var lname = $("#INAkhir").val();
        /*end of get data*/

        //create form_data for post data on ajax PHP
        var file_data = $("#chImage").prop("files")[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("file", file_data);
        form_data.append("PHPIDUser", IDUser);
        form_data.append("PHPUfname", fname);
        form_data.append("PHPUlname", lname);

        sessionStorage.statusUpdate = 1;
        loadingPage(2000);

        $.ajax ({

            type: "POST",
            url: host+'/tosomewhere/db_userUpdate.php',

            data: form_data,

            contentType : false,
            processData : false,

            beforeSend: function() {

                loadingPageW(1);

            },
            success: function(data){

                if (data == 'update') {

                    loadingPage(2000);
                    alert("Success");
                    window.location = 'Profile.html';

                } else if (data == 'failed') {

                    alert('Failed');
                    location.reload();
                    loadingPage(1000);
                    window.location = 'UpdateProfil.html';

                } else {

                    alert('Connection Lost');
                    location.reload();
                    loadingPage(1000);
                    window.location = 'UpdateProfil.html';

                }
            }, //for error message
            error: function (xhr, errorStats, errorMsg) {

                alert("error: "+xhr.errorStats+" , "+errorMsg);

            },
            complete: function() {

                loadingPageW(2);

            }

        });

};
```

Is there any suggest to pass it? Because I need to reach at least this version to the user(s).

FYI, I already search it, and I get the nearest question to this :

> [JS FormData object not defined for PhoneGap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188684/js-formdata-object-not-defined-for-phonegap-in-android)

But on that question, I didn't get any further information / answer (why it not support or what to do).
If the answer is that, so I need detail answer if the phonegap not support the FormData object? (as I already mentioned, I need the 'why' and 'what to do' answer)

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You didn't say exactly *where* the uncaught reference error was. From what I see on CanIUse (http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata), FormData should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean 'where'? As I already said before, I get error on my android phone (that I connect to eclipse when compiling). Anyway thanks for the link. I never know that link was exist :P From what I'm seeing from your link, it seems Android browser 2.3.6 not supported FormData, am I wrong?. By the way, any other suggestion @RaymondCamden to pass this in my android (2.3.6) ? :) Thanks again! :D

Comment: Ah - if it isn't supported, just use the FileTransfer plugin. Lets you upload/download files.

Comment: I see then, Maybe I need other method, seems FileTransfer little bit complex for me. Thanks for your advice anyway :)